# Cakephp .htaccess redirection

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I have a site running on cakephp and I have created another site and put it on /newsite folder.

When I try to access that newsite using: mysitename.com/newsite

If is giving cakephp controller missing error.

Basically I think it has something to change in the cakephp .htaccess file to redirect properly to the newsite.

Can anyone suggest any answer?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following before your rewrite rules should prevent CakePHP from treating existing directory or file names as controllers.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

See the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/917/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess).

Answer (score 0):

just put your new site in the webroot folder.

Comment: That would cause the URLs to look like /app/webroot/newsite. You'd have to modify the .htaccess file once again like so: `RewriteRule    ^newsite/* app/webroot/newsite/$1 [L]`. I guess it depends on how you'd prefer to structure your directories.